# R: Swapping every second row in an array

Tags: r, rows, swap

I'm looking to swap second every row in an array. I do not know the length of the array beforehand. I do, however, know that it will be divisible by 2.

As an example:

> 101   102   147   148

would become

> 102   101   148   147

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say your vector ("array" is sooo Fortran) is `x`.

```
even <- seq(from=2, to=length(x), by=2)
odd <- even - 1
xnew <- x
xnew[even] <- x[odd]
xnew[odd] <- x[even]
```

You could make the code more terse, but this probably makes it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: ok, great! Haha, my "vector" adjusted perfectly!! Thanks for your help, much appreciated! Mike

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional version that dimensions the vector into a matrix and then swaps each pair round and concatenates the result...

```
#  Your data
x <- c( 101 , 102 , 147 , 148 )

#  Simple function
swap <- function(x){
  c( apply( t( matrix( x , length( x ) /2  , byrow = TRUE ) ) , 2 , rev ) )
}

swap( x )
# [1] 102 101 148 147

swap( 1:10 )
# [1]  2  1  4  3  6  5  8  7 10  9
```

And here's a second, faster solution that eliminates the use of `apply` and uses entirely vectorised operations...

```
swap2 <- function(x){
  id <- seq_along( x ) %% 2 == 0
  c( t( matrix( c(x[id],x[!id]) , sum(id) ) ) )
}

swap2(1:10)
# [1]  2  1  4  3  6  5  8  7 10  9
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess its pretty simple using for loop

> for( i=0 ;i< arr.length;i+=2) { swap(arr[i],arr[i+1]) }

Comment: sorry i didnt notice the R in the question